# Left Matrix Division and Numpy Solve

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave, linear-algebra

I am trying to convert code that contains the \ operator from Matlab (Octave) to Python. Sample code

```matlab
B = [2;4]
b = [4;4]
B \ b
```

This works and produces 1.2 as an answer. Using this web page

http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html

I translated that as:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin
B = np.array([[2],[4]])
b = np.array([[4],[4]])
print lin.solve(B,b)
```

This gave me an error:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Array must be square
```

How come Matlab \ works with non square matrix for B?

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Matlab did indeed define a beautiful (if deceptively simple) language for mathematics.  It is clear that numpy and pyplotlib inherit much from it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [MathWorks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) for left matrix division:

> If A is an m-by-n matrix with m ~= n and B is a column vector with m
>   components, or a matrix with several such columns, then X = A\B is the
>   solution in the least squares sense to the under- or overdetermined
>   system of equations AX = B. In other words, X minimizes norm(A*X - B),
>   the length of the vector AX - B.

The equivalent in numpy is [np.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq):

```
In [15]: B = np.array([[2],[4]])

In [16]: b = np.array([[4],[4]])

In [18]: x,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(B,b)

In [19]: x
Out[19]: array([[ 1.2]])
```

Answer (score 14):

Matlab will actually do a number of different operations when the \ operator is used, depending on the shape of the matrices involved (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) for more details). In you example, Matlab is returning a least squares solution, rather than solving the linear equation directly, as would happen with a square matrix. To get the same behaviour in numpy, do this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin
B = np.array([[2],[4]])
b = np.array([[4],[4]])
print np.linalg.lstsq(B,b)[0]
```

which should give you the same solution as Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

You can form the left inverse:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin
B = np.array([[2],[4]])
b = np.array([[4],[4]])

B_linv = lin.solve(B.T.dot(B), B.T)
c = B_linv.dot(b)
print('c\n', c)
```

Result:

```
c
 [[ 1.2]]
```

Actually, we can simply run the solver once, without forming an inverse, like this:

```
c = lin.solve(B.T.dot(B), B.T.dot(b))
print('c\n', c)
```

Result:

```
c
 [[ 1.2]]
```

.... as before

Why?  Because:

We have:

[image]

Multiply through by `B.T`, gives us:

[image]

Now, `B.T.dot(B)` is square, full rank, does have an inverse.  And therefore we can multiply through by the inverse of `B.T.dot(B)`, or use a solver, as above, to get `c`.